# Unequal length vectors to matrix in R

Tags: r

I have grocery basket data like this:

```
 rbind(v1 = c("fruit", "semi-finished bread", "margarine", "ready soups"), 
       v2 = c("fruit", "yogurt", "coffee",""),
       v3 = c("whole milk","","",""), 
       v4 = c("fruit", "yogurt", "cream cheese", "meat spreads"))
...
   [,1]         [,2]                  [,3]           [,4]          
v1 "fruit"      "semi-finished bread" "margarine"    "ready soups" 
v2 "fruit"      "yogurt"              "coffee"       ""            
v3 "whole milk" ""                    ""             ""            
v4 "fruit"      "yogurt"              "cream cheese" "meat spreads"
...
```

How can I get it to a form where each item is a column and 0/1 indicating whether or not the basket contains this item?

```
fruit;semi-finished bread;margarine;ready soups;yogurt;coffee;whole milk;cream cheese ;meat spreads
1;1;1;1;0;0;0;0;0
1;0;0;0;1;1;0;0;0
0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0
1;0;0;0;1;0;0;1;1
...
```

*EDIT The challenge is in the raw data since it's not in order (fruit is sometimes first, sometimes second and so on). Empty "slots" (ie when the number of items < max number of items per basket) are in the end of the row.

It would in some way be needed to first determine the columns (all items in the data set) and then define which items are found on each basket. There can be over 1000 items in total and 1 million rows so manual work needs to be minimal.

Comment: Perhaps not suitable for your actual data but see, also, `table(row(dat), dat)` (assuming `dat` is your "matrix".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
elements<-strsplit(x,";",fixed=TRUE)
columns<-unique(unlist(elements))
res<-do.call(rbind,lapply(elements,function(x) as.integer(columns %in% x)))
colnames(res)<-columns
#you can write the content on res on a file or on the console with write.csv
write.csv2(res,row.names=FALSE,quote=FALSE)
#fruit;semi-finished bread;margarine;ready soups;yogurt;coffee;whole milk;cream cheese ;meat spreads
#1;1;1;1;0;0;0;0;0
#1;0;0;0;1;1;0;0;0
#0;0;0;0;0;0;1;0;0
#1;0;0;0;1;0;0;1;1
```

**Data**

```
x<-c("fruit;semi-finished bread;margarine;ready soups", "fruit;yogurt;coffee;", 
"whole milk;", "fruit;yogurt;cream cheese ;meat spreads")
```

Answer (score 7):

With the data

```
x <- c("fruit;semi-finished bread;margarine;ready soups",
       "fruit;yogurt;coffee;",
       "whole milk;",
       "fruit;yogurt;cream cheese ;meat spreads")
```

The following function takes the character vector of basket items and
creates an incidence matrix

```
baskets2incidence <- function(baskets) {
    ## process to computable elements
    baskets <- strsplit(baskets, " *; *") # each basket a vector of items
    items <- unique(unlist(baskets))

    ## pre-allocate the result matrix
    m <- matrix(0, length(baskets), length(items), dimnames=list(NULL, items))

    ## row and column index of basket items
    ridx <- rep(seq_along(baskets), lengths(baskets))
    cidx <- match(unlist(baskets), items)

    ## update the result matrix -- a 2-column matrix can serve as index
    m[matrix(c(ridx, cidx), 2)] <- 1
    m
}
```

The result is

```
> baskets2incidence(x)
     fruit semi-finished bread margarine ready soups yogurt coffee whole milk
[1,]     1                   1         1           0      0      0          0
[2,]     1                   1         0           0      0      0          0
[3,]     1                   1         0           0      0      0          0
[4,]     1                   1         0           0      0      0          0
     cream cheese meat spreads
[1,]            0            0
[2,]            0            0
[3,]            0            0
[4,]            0            0
```

The approach does not use loops, so will scale well.

With 1000 items and a million rows, the matrix will be large (a billion elements) and very sparse. It then makes sense to use a sparse matrix and to use row `ridx` and column `cidx` indexes directly, rather than to make a full matrix

```
library(Matrix)
m <- Matrix(0, length(baskets), length(items), dimnames=list(NULL, items),
                sparse=TRUE)

m[matrix(c(ridx, cidx), ncol=2)] <- 1
```

The updated function is

```
baskets2incidence <- function(baskets) {
    ## process to computable elements
    baskets <- strsplit(baskets, " *; *") # each basket a vector of items
    items <- unique(unlist(baskets))

    ## pre-allocate the sparse matrix
    m <- Matrix(0, length(baskets), length(items), dimnames=list(NULL, items),
                sparse=TRUE)

    ## row and column index of basket items
    ridx <- rep(seq_along(baskets), lengths(baskets))
    cidx <- match(unlist(baskets), items)

    ## update and return
    m[matrix(c(ridx, cidx), ncol=2)] <- 1
    m
}
```

and the results are

```
> baskets2incidence(x)
4 x 9 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
     fruit semi-finished bread margarine ready soups yogurt coffee whole milk
[1,]     1                   1         1           1      .      .          .
[2,]     1                   .         .           .      1      1          .
[3,]     .                   .         .           .      .      .          1
[4,]     1                   .         .           .      1      .          .
     cream cheese meat spreads
[1,]            .            .
[2,]            .            .
[3,]            .            .
[4,]            1            1
```

For the sample data, I would suggest reading it into a list of baskets rather than data frame, e.g.,

```
url <- "http://www.salemmarafi.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/groceries.csv"
baskets <- strsplit(readLines(url), ",", fixed=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you please add a version when source data (x) is a data.frame. I'm struggling to get the lengths(baskets) since in data.frames all the baskets have the same length. Example data: http://www.salemmarafi.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/groceries.csv

Answer (score 4):

We can use `mtabulate` from `qdapTools`

```
library(qdapTools)
+(!!mtabulate(as.data.frame(t(df1))))
#  fruit margarine ready soups semi-finished bread V5 coffee yogurt whole milk
#V1     1         1           1                   1  0      0      0          0
#V2     1         0           0                   0  1      1      1          0
#V3     0         0           0                   0  1      0      0          1
#V4     1         0           0                   0  0      0      1          0
#   cream cheese meat spreads
#V1            0            0
#V2            0            0
#V3            0            0
#V4            1            1
```

If it is a `vector` as showed in the example from @nicola's post

```
mtabulate(strsplit(x, ';'))
```

#### data

```
 df1 <- structure(list(v1 = c("fruit", "fruit", 
 "whole milk", "fruit"
 ), v2 = c("semi-finished bread", "yogurt", "", "yogurt"),
  v3 = c("margarine", 
 "coffee", "", "cream cheese"), v4 = c("ready soups", "", 
 "", 
"meat spreads")), .Names = c("v1", "v2", "v3", "v4"), 
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 2):

I do like  the economy of mtabulate, but I already had cobbled this togetehr so:

```
txt <- "fruit;semi-finished bread;margarine;ready soups
fruit;yogurt;coffee;
whole milk;
fruit;yogurt;cream cheese ;meat spreads"
foods <- scan(text=txt,what="",sep=";")
foods <- unique(foods)

out <- paste0( foods, collapse=";")
for ( lines in readLines(textConnection(txt)) ) { out <- c(out, paste(as.numeric(foods %in%  scan(text=lines,what="",sep=";")  ), collapse=";"))}
Read 4 items
Read 4 items
Read 2 items
Read 4 items  # could use quiet=TRUE
out
####---
[1] "fruit;semi-finished bread;margarine;ready soups;yogurt;coffee;;whole milk;cream cheese ;meat spreads"
[2] "1;1;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0"                                                                                 
[3] "1;0;0;0;1;1;1;0;0;0"                                                                                 
[4] "0;0;0;0;0;0;1;1;0;0"                                                                                 
[5] "1;0;0;0;1;0;0;0;1;1"
```